# Why is it saying not able to Import

Tags: python, python-module

I am trying to import another file (tiles.py) into my main (main.py) file, and it has some importing errors. I am trying to import a class called Tile into my main. the error is

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "c:\Users\shireen\Desktop\Clear Code\main.py", line 3, in <module>
 from tiles import Tile
 ImportError: cannot import name 'Tile' from 'tiles' 
 (c:\Users\shireen\Desktop\ClearCode\tiles.py)
```

My main.py file code:

```
import pygame, sys
from settings import *
from tiles import Tile

# Pygame setup
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
test_tile = pygame.sprite.Group(Tile((100, 100), 200))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.fill('black')
    test_tile.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

My tiles.py file code:

```
import pygame

class Tile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos,size):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((size, size))
        self.image.fill('grey')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos)
```

Comment: Your `tiles.py` file must be different from what you posted.  Or else you have two different files named `tiles.py`.  Double-check that `c:\Users\shireen\Desktop\ClearCode\tiles.py` is the correct file.

Comment: Yes, it is I just checked they are in the same folder.

Comment: Also, I should mention that I am following along with a tutorial (to get a feel for Pygame) and have done everything right step-by-step.

Comment: Strange.  Show us the output of this code `import tiles; print(dir(tiles))`

Comment: PS C:\Users\shireen\Desktop\Clear Code> & "C:/Program Files/Python310/python.exe" 

"c:/Users/shireen/Desktop/Clear Code/main.py"

pygame 2.3.0 (SDL 2.24.2, Python 3.10.9)

Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html

704

['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']

Comment: Well, that output indeed says that there is nothing named `Tiles` in the module.  Somehow, the `tiles.py` you posted is not the same as the one that is being imported.  Maybe you have two different files named `tiles.py` in different directories, or maybe you didn't save the changes after adding the `Tiles` class, or something...

Comment: That was it thank you. I had to save the changes

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by a space in the path. Compare this:

```
File "c:\Users\shireen\Desktop\Clear Code\main.py", line 3, in <module>
```

and

```
(c:\Users\shireen\Desktop\ClearCode\tiles.py)
```

You are just need to rename "Clear Code" to "ClearCode" or smth

Comment: Nope still doesnt work